# Не получается передать массив данных (из базы данных) методом ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

```
<?php //php страница qwe.php для обработки ajax запроса    

   require_once "blocks/head.php";

   connectDB();
   $add = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM teacher");  
   while($row = $add->fetch_assoc()){
        $lesson[] = $row["surname"];
   };
   $mysqli->close();    
   $json = json_encode($lesson);
   echo $json;

?>

<script> //сам ajax запрос

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.get("qwe.php", function(data){                    
            console.log(data);      
        });
    });

</script>
```

В require_once "blocks/head.php" находится подключение jquery + функция connect():

```
<?php
   function connectDB(){
       global $mysqli;
       $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "login", "password", "nameDB");
       $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
   };   
?>
```

В итоге в консоли выводит массив, но перед ним сначала какой-то html код и сам массив закодирован, выглядит это так:

- пример того что выводит перед массивом:

> <meta charset="utf-8"> 
>   <title><br /> 
>   <font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1'

- в таком виде выводит массив:

["\u041a\u0443\u0440\u043e\u0432","\u0421\u043c\u043e\u0433\u0430\u043b\u0435\u0432\u0430","\u0421\u043f\u0438\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0430",

И ЕЩЕ НЕ МЕНЕЕ ВАЖНОЕ, если я укажу dataType: "json" например вот такой запрос:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "qwe.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);  
        }
});
```

то в консоли вообще пусто, но массив так же закодирован (в браузере в "NETWORK" возвращает)

ПЕРЕЧИСЛЮ ТО ЧЕГО НЕ НУЖНО ПРЕДЛАГАТЬ И ТО ЧТО НЕ ПОМОГАЕТ:

```
var teacher = <?php echo json_encode($lesson); ?>;  - это мне не нужно

и еще не работают такие функции как JSON.parse, parse.JSON, $.JSONparse (выдает ошибку типа: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0) я так понял из-за непонятного html кода в начале, он по ходу как массив воспринимается, я так и не понял, мучаюсь 2 дня и буду ОЧЕНЬ РАД ЕСЛИ КТО ЗНАЕТ РЕШЕНИЕ =)
```

Comment: "В require_once "blocks/head.php" находится подключение jquery ..." - как находится? head.php - вероятно содержит вызовы `echo`, выводящие html.

Comment: Вынесите `connectDB` в отдельный файл и используйте этот файл вместо head.php.

Comment: я конечно понимаю что так нужно, но я это сделал однажды и просто забил на это потому что при вызове этой функции из отдельного файла пишет ошибку (Fatal error: Call to undefined function connectDB()) ответ на вопрос "почему так" я не нашёл

Comment: @ArtyomDrebednyov Вероятно забивать не нужно, а нужно разобратся в чём ошибка и исправить её. Первый комментарий скорее всего правильно идентифицировал вашу проблему.

Comment: я сделал по "ГОСТУ" (переписал функцию в отдельный файл и вызвал его) БД подключилась, но к сожалению аналогичный результат в console, может скинуть скриншот, тут так можно вообще?)

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл ответ на другом форуме:

```
$json = json_encode($lesson, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```